# Error passing boost::variant derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-variant

Why copying `foo` instance generates error: 
`error: call of overloaded 'convert_construct(foo&, long int)' is ambiguous` ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct foo : public boost::variant<int, std::string>
{
    using boost::variant<int, std::string>::variant;
};

int main()
{
  foo f(111);
  // auto g = f;  // ERROR -> call of overloaded 'convert_construct(foo&, long int)' is ambiguous
}
```

Live example: [cpp.sh/7f3xy](http://cpp.sh/7f3xy)

Comment: gcc accepts it, but not clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c78620c2fd71ac92). No need of lambda btw, any copy constructed object reproduce the issue: `auto g = f;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 applied simplification to example code